# How do I fix weird edge plots using parametric plot, fractional part, and irrationals?

Tags: plotting

I am trying to plot the following equation, which is parametrically defined and use FractionalPart. The idea behind the function is that a ball is bouncing off the walls.

```
f[u_, m_, x0_] := Abs[FractionalPart[(m*u + x0)/2. + .1]*2. - 1.]
g[u_, m_, y0_] := Abs[FractionalPart[(m*u + y0)/2. + 1.]*2. - 1.]
path10 = ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 10},
PlotRange -> {{0, 1.1}, {0, 1.1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

But when I plot, I am missing x > .98 and y > .98. If I extend this and have u = 50, I get even weirder issues.[image]

```
path50 = ParametricPlot[
           {f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 50},
           PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Exclusions -> None]
```

Parts of the lines stop appearing roughly .02 from all the boundaries, and all the lines that hit near (0, 0) suddenly converge to (0, 0).[image]

Comment: Try adding the option `MaxRecursion -> 15`. The issue you're seeing happens because the sampling of the curve isn't fine enough. Allowing the sampling algorithm to improve its sampling more times (i.e. increasing `MaxRecursion`) usually helps.

Answer (score 2):

It's either [`MaxRecursion`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MaxRecursion.html)as C.E. pointed out above, or [`PlotPoints`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotPoints.html). The difference is in the adaptive sampling (first) vs. initial sampling (second). Both solve your problem:

```
f[u_, m_, x0_] := Abs[FractionalPart[(m*u + x0)/2. + .1]*2. - 1.]
g[u_, m_, y0_] := Abs[FractionalPart[(m*u + y0)/2. + 1.]*2. - 1.]
ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 50}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   PlotPoints -> #] & /@ {5, 10, 20, 50, 100}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

```
ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 50}, 
   PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Exclusions -> None, 
   MaxRecursion -> #] & /@ {1, 2, 5, 10, 15}
```

> [image: Blockquote]

In your specific case, `PlotPoints` tends to work slightly faster.

```
{ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 50}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Exclusions -> None, 
    PlotPoints -> 150] // RepeatedTiming // First,
 ParametricPlot[{f[u, 3., 0.], g[u, Pi, .2]}, {u, 0, 50}, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, Exclusions -> None, 
    MaxRecursion -> 8] // RepeatedTiming // First}
```

> {0.0641, 0.074}